# How can I implement an atomic incr and decr on top of an eventually consistent key-value store?

Tags: atomic

How can I implement an atomic incr and decr on an eventually consistent key-value store?

Is this even possible? Does being eventually consistent mean that I just have to accept that a value will never be for sure?

Comment: Purely in the abstract or on some specific database?

Comment: on riak which was the keystore I was using at the time